# How to estimate the number of people outdoors in a city?

Tags: population

Currently working on a project about the public facilities' usage in NYC.

Now I want to find the relationship between the number of public facilities and the number of people in the corresponding district.

However, it makes no sense to count in the people who stay indoors and have no access to the public facilities. Thus it makes me wonder how to estimate the number of people outdoors.

The only dataset I have is the total population of the district.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "The only dataset I have is the total population of the district." You mean a single number? Or does the dataset have rows and columns?

Comment: @Salmonstrikes It's just a small data frame, every borough has a corresponding population number.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need to enrich your dataset somehow.

In a city like NYC, you could get the [number of people who used mass transit](http://www.mta.info/news-subway-new-york-city-transit-ridership-record-breaking/2014/10/22/more-6-million-customers-ride) on a given day as a good estimate of who went out that day.

MTA usage may not be as close an estimate in Queens or Staten Island where more people use cars as it is in Brooklyn or Manhattan. It would need to be a combination of traffic and mass transit usage. And again, it will only be a rough estimate.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, it is a good idea, so i should also find the bus rider numbers and the number of cars on the road. But what about people walking??